# batch reclassify rasters with different elevation ranges

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder, reclassify

I have about 500 elevation rasters, and I would like to use modelbuilder with an iterator to reclassify each raster into distinct elevation ranges (0-1m, 1-2m, 2-3m, 3-4m, 4-5m). I believe my problem is that each raster has a different range of elevation, is there a work around this? I tried mosaic-ing all the rasters together but reclassify tool does not work on this mosaic.

Comment: Are you using a continuous DEM in floating point format?

Comment: yes it is a floating point

Comment: What happens when the reclass fails?  Have statistics been calculated on the DEMs?

Comment: Yes I calculated all statistics. I use Iterate rasters and the Reclassify tool and I get the error message "The Input maximum (6.784375) is out of range.."

Comment: Why not create another class >5m?

Comment: When I am in the Reclassify window I select Natural breaks and make the breaks at 1,2,3 and 4 so I thought that the last class would be anything above 4 which is what I want. But I still get the same error message

Comment: You will want your highest class to explicitly cover the highest possible value in any of your rasters. The natural breaks approach that you mention is probably defining that class within the ranges of a single raster (e.g. 4 - 4.67) which means that any raster with a larger value will be out of range.  Manually define your last class as 4 - 6.8 (if that is your highest value) and you should be fine.

Comment: Unfortunately while trying to iterate this using model builder when I open the reclassify tool to change the values the original values do not reflect the entire range of the values across all the rasters, just the first raster so when I manually define the last class, I get the same error message saying it is out of range

Answer (score 2):

Create a CSV file:

```
Low,High,Val
0,1,1
1,2,2
2,3,3
3,4,4
4,5,5
```

It is best to import it to a dbf, INFO or GDB table after entering the text values.

Then use [Reclassify by Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Reclass_by_Table/009z000000sq000000/), it doesn't care what the ranges of individual rasters are. According to the documentation, build the statistics first then run this tool (iteratively if you like). From_value_field is `Low`, To_value_field is `High` and Output_value_field is `Val`. Change the numbers in the Val column to suit your expected outputs, the values I have shown here are illustrative only.

Depending on what you want in your output you can specify `Missing Values: DATA` which will copy all values not listed in the table as they are or `Missing Values: NODATA` which will set all values not in the table to NODATA.

Comment: Hi, I am creating a csv file with exactly what you wrote (3 columns with my own "val" column) and using Reclass by Table and selecting missing values as no data. I am getting ERROR 010328 and ERROR 010267. Both syntax errors. Any idea what I could be doing incorrectly?

Comment: Is there anything *with* the errors. Could you get a screen grab and post it with the question. Did you try to use the CSV directly or did you import it to another table format as suggested? If you converted it does the table look correct?

Comment: I see that I made the mistake of not importing the .csv file into a gdb first. I began the reclass by table tool again and got no error message. Unfortunately it has been running for 6 hours for one raster so am not sure this will actually work. It could be that I am working with LIDAR data which is much more intense and does take a long time to process.

Comment: Been down that road before, CSV isn't the best format. How big is your LiDAR dataset? Perhaps clip a small bit out to prove it's working before running it on a large dataset. Also look at your TEMP and TMP environment variables, most Esri raster functions copy the raster to the temp/tmp directory and process it there; you may be having quota/disc problems in your temp directories.

Comment: I have the same proccess to build with a lot of rasters, but the problem I need to Reclass slope base on percent value, how do I put the value on the table to be load by Reclass by Table tool?

Comment: @Zery, numbers are just numbers. Percents range from 0 to 100, however in the case of slope in rare instances values can be greater than 100 i.e. more than 100% vertical increment for the horizontal displacement. If you need to get min & max you can get that from a arcpy.Raster object and write the table on the fly using python file I/O; I think in this case if you made the last band 100.0 to 1000000.0 that should be a general catch-all.

Comment: get the min & max is what I'm thinking of, this would be my next attempt to do it. thank you for the arcpy object. I don't really understand about changing the last band?

Comment: The table contains ranges (bands) of values and the output value, given the example any value from 0 to 1 will be 1 in the output, 1 to 2 will be 2 in the output and so on. Depending on how you want to classify your slope, whether by defined ranges (same for all) or a set number of classes between minimum and maximum (different for all) dictates how the lookup table (csv) is created. If you have a specific example please post a question for more specific help.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to use Feature Analyst (extension from Overwatch) and used "Image Fusion" tool and clicked "custom", clicked band 1 and input a script assigning values to elevation classes. Then I used batch processing in Lidar Analyst extension to batch process all of the rasters this way. I think regular GIS tools sometimes have trouble handling a lot of LIDAR data